# Express: cannot access an array of numbers even though it is in the request body

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

Express / Typescript:

```
export const updateSettings = catchErrors(async (req, res) => {

  console.log("updateSettings req.body: ", req.body)
  
  const { organizationId, formdata, updatedItems, updateQuota } = req.body; 

  console.log("organizationId: ", organizationId);
  console.log("formdata: ", formdata);
  console.log("updatedItems: ", updatedItems);
  console.log("updateQuota: ", updateQuota);
  console.log("req.body.updateQuota: ", req.body.updateQuota);

  res.respond({'message': 'Settings updated successfully!' })

});
```

the console log for `req.body` is as follows:

```
updateSettings req.body:  {
  username: 'staff_a',
  organizationId: '2',
  formData: '{"offDays":[0,6,1],"officeHourStart":"1899-12-31T09:00:00.000+09:00","officeHourEnd":"1899-12-31T18:00:00.000+09:00","displayLanguage":"cn","timezone":"beijing","doctorQuotas":{"5":5,"6":10}}',
  updatedItems: [ 'displayLanguage', 'timezone', 'billingClosingDay', 'offDays' ],
  updatedQuota: [ 6, 5 ]
}
```

As you can see, there are fields `updatedQuota` and `updatedItems`. One is an array of strings and the other is an array of numbers;

However, after the destructoring line `const { organizationId, formdata, updatedItems, updateQuota } = req.body;` , some of fields are fine, but some fields becomes undefined:

```
organizationId:  2
formdata:  undefined
updatedItems:  [ 'displayLanguage', 'timezone', 'billingClosingDay', 'offDays' ]
updateQuota:  undefined
```

if I access the `req.body.updateQuota` alone by printing it   `console.log("req.body.updateQuota: ", req.body.updateQuota);`, it is also empty:

```
req.body.updateQuota:  undefined
```

Why is it that things are clearly contained in `req.body`, but cannot be accessed or extracted?

Comment: Typo: `updateQuota`<>`updatedQuota`, `formData`<>`formdata`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`formData` or `formdata` ?

`updatedQuota` or `updateQuota` ?

Answer (score 0):

req.body has updatedQuota not "updateQuota"

Answer (score -1):

```
{username, organizationId, formData, updatedItems, updateQuota} = req.body
```